# Get Random Product Listing Based On Type or Category

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with a table containing details as below

```
    p_id  p_name  p_desc  p_type
    ----  ------  ------  -------
       1  Pro1    Pro1d   premium
       2  Pro2    Pro2d   normal
       3  Pro3    Pro3d   classic
       4  Pro4    Pro4d   normal
       5  Pro5    Pro5d   deluxe
```

I want to list products in such a way that it will contain all results. But
it will display products in random order. It will display some normal type
products, then premium product, again normal type product, a deluxe product,
then again normal type, classic product. Will it be possible with  a 
MySQL query

Comment: Possible, yes. Psuedo-random, yes, but expensive for large sets.  Pseudo-random but following some rules, that would be convoluted.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to return the rows in a pseudo-random order? Yes. But it will be expensive for large sets.

Add an ORDER BY clause to your query:

```
... ORDER BY RAND()
```

That will be expensive for large sets because the RAND() function will need to be evaluated for every row, and the value returned by the RAND() function will require a "Using filesort" operation.

There's no guarantee that the first rows will be "normal", followed by "premium". It's pseudo-random, so all of the "premium" products could be first, or be sprinkled in the middle, or whatever.